# Is it possible in excel to output value into blank cell without using paste special?

Tags: microsoft-excel, paste

Is there any function or other way that takes result of formula and pastes value to given blank cell without formula?
It's quite annoying to use copy paste special->value or it's derivates.
For example:
A1=1

A2=2

A3=1+2

A4=function"paste special"(copy from "A3";paste value "A5")

A5=3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simple formula `A5=A3` is not enough for you?

Comment: @Akina point of paste special->value is that it breaks connection between formula and result so the value doesn't change. If you use A5=A3 then changing any of the parameters A5 also is changing.

Comment: If so then macro or VBA procedure seems to be the only option.

Comment: Using macros is a good approach.